# Is logistic regression or a random forest model better suited for this particular data?

Tags: regression, categorical-data, random-forest

I am developing two separate models. I chose to use logistic regression to analyze both models. I am not familiar with random forest models, so I wanted to make sure my reasoning for choosing logistic regression over random forest was sound.

Model 1: For this dataset, all independent variables are continuous (canopy cover, tree density, and housing density). The dependent variable is the presence or absence of a particular species of lizard. I chose to use logistic regression because (1) I would like an interpretable model. I want to understand which factors have an impact on lizard presence, (2) I'd like to be able to produce probabilities (odds ratios) and an ROC curve, so I can understand how various thresholds affect the true and false positive rates, and (3) the independent variables have a linear relationship with the log odds of the outcome. Overall, my goal is to understand how various environmental factors affect lizard occurrence. I don't feel a random forest would provide me with that information in an interpretable format.

Model 2: For this model, I have four categorical variables (sky cover, year, observer, and season). The dependent variable is the same as the first model: lizard presence or absence, except I am not interested in predicting lizard absence or presence. The purpose of this model is to determine what factors affect detection. For example, does a sunny sky affect the probability a lizard is detected? As with the first model, I'd like this model to be easily interpretable, which is why I chose logistic regression for this as well. However, I've read that random forest may be more suitable for categorical data. Still, I only want to determine which factors affect detection, and I think logistic regression is better suited for that.

Are either of these explanations ill-informed? Would random forest or another type of model be better?

Comment: Where did you read that random forest is more suitable for categorical data? It’s hard to understand the real meaning of that claim without context. Can you [edit] to include the quotation and full citation information? All of your goals seem to be satisfied by logistic regression, except for the claim made in the reference you allude to, *unless* you're interested in nonlinear effects of independent variables or interactions of independent variables. Random forest can do well in those cases, but the results can be challenging to interpret.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I read that random forest may be better for categorical data here: https://www.quora.com/When-should-random-forest-be-used-over-logistic-regression-for-classification-and-vice-versa, so it was by no means an official source. Just a thread.

Comment: Well, I guess that's one person's opinion. It's hard to know what they mean from the single, unsupported claim. It's my experience that the value of any statistical advice is only as good as the evidence it offers in support of its claims.